# Change snackbar size

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-snackbar

Im trying to show an SnackBar but it is bigger (in y) than expected.

## Expected

[image]

## Result

[image]

I tried setting paddings and margins on the style but it just change the left and right paddings.

## Already tried

As a desperate way I have this:

- App Theme:

```
<item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Snackbar</item>
<item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Snackbar.TextView</item>
```

- Styles:

```
    <style name="Snackbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.FullWidth">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/lh_slate_opacity_90</item>

        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Snackbar.TextView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>

        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

I get the same behaviour for:

- `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05`
- `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0`

It changes the background color and font family but not the top and bottom padding of the snackbar.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official API for that, but you can override the padding resource in your `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="design_snackbar_padding_vertical" tools:override="true">5dp</dimen>
```

Here you can find all dimensions you can override with the same way
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/res/values/dimens.xml